# Why is convolution operation an integral?

Tags: convolution, mathematical-statistics, integral

I was reading the wonderful book on Deep Learning (http://www.deeplearningbook.org) trying to understand convolution. It uses an example in the convolution chapter (http://www.deeplearningbook.org/contents/convnets.html) which is pictured of a function x(t) of the position of a spaceship and w(a) as a weighted avg. Of reading of age a. The convolution is shown in the image as an integral of x(a)w(t-a) hence the convolution.

I don't understand the intuition of this example and of convolution. Have tried researching and not helped. In particular why this is an integral not just a straight function of s(t) = x(a)w(t-a)

MANY THANKS!

[image]

Comment: The convolution $s(t)$ is a function of one argument. Whereas your proposed $s(t)=x(a)w(t-a)$ requires specification of $a$ and so is really a function of two arguments. This would also not draw in information from the whole of the input, only something about what was happening at time $a$ and at time $t-a$.

Comment: There are several equivalent ways to describe the function.  Remember this: the universe didn't invent convolution, humans did.  Math says there are 5 different species of language to say the same thing: words, numbers, flowcharts, graphs, and algebra; I don't mean those as equivalent ways.  Remember how you learned integrals as the limit of discrete sums.  You can think of the convolution in those terms.  I really like to think of convolution in terms of its identity function, the dirac delta.  Looking at it in the frequency domain (Laplace is easier than Fourier, but equivalent) helps too.

Answer (score 1):

Convolution is a well-documented topic.
You can have a look [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/255929/can-someone-intuitively-explain-what-the-convolution-integral-is) and [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/5892/what-is-convolution-intuitively) as a good start.

Going back to your question, keeping it really simple, the convolution operator includes the integral, because what you are doing is, going back to the example you provided, averaging by a function $w$; and in the example you provided, you got something that is continuous.